# uninitialized_X functions that use the allocator constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, allocator, placement-new, c++20

**Is there a version of [`uninitialized_value_construct`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_value_construct) that uses the an allocator to construct the element in place instead of placement `new`?**

This below is the prototypical implementation of `uninitialized_value_construct`; however I am looking for one where the allocator is passed so I can use the line `alloc.construct(std::addressof(*current))` instead of `::new (std::addressof(*current))`.

```
template<class ForwardIt>
void uninitialized_value_construct(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last)
{
    using Value = typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::value_type;
    ForwardIt current = first;
    try {
        for (; current != last; ++current) {
            ::new (static_cast<void*>(std::addressof(*current))) Value();
        }
    } catch (...) {
        std::destroy(first, current);
        throw;
    }
}
```

In C++20, there is [uninitialized_construct_using_allocator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_construct_using_allocator) but it is not clear what it is for or how to use it.

---

**EDIT:** After a conversation with @NicolBolas, I ended up implementing these pair of functions (that I wish were in the `std::`). For my needs (and without loss of generality, I will do this for other `uninitialized_X` functions.

```
template<class Alloc, class ForwardIt, class Size, class AT = typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc>>
ForwardIt uninitialized_value_construct_n(Alloc& a, ForwardIt first, Size n){
    using T = typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIt>::value_type;
    ForwardIt current = first;
    try{
        for(; n > 0; (void) ++current, --n) 
            AT::construct(a, std::addressof(*current), T());
//          ::new (static_cast<void*>(std::addressof(*current))) T();
        return current;
    }catch(...){destroy(a, first, current); throw;}
}
```

```
template<class Alloc, class ForwardIt, typename AT = typename std::allocator_traits<Alloc> >
void destroy(Alloc& a, ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last){
    for(; first != last; ++first) 
        AT::destroy(a, std::addressof(*first));
    //  destroy_at(std::addressof(*first));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, there is no ranged version of `uninitialized_construct` that takes an allocator.

As for what `uninitialized_construct_using_allocator` is for, it construct a single object of the given type with the given arguments through the allocator. That might *seem* trivial to do (`std::allocator_traits<Alloc>::construct(t, alloc, std::forward<Args>(args)...)`), but it does it in such a way that the allocator will be propagated correctly to `scoped_allocator`s used by that `T`. This requires a [bunch of techniques](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uses_allocator) that are not well known and are not easily understood, so there's a specific function to do it.

Comment: Ok, it seems to me that all `uninitialized_` functions that use placement new should have an `allocator.construct` version, if I am not that crazy. What I am not sure if it should be part of the allocators traits, a free function, or a member of the allocator.

Comment: @alfC: `construct` is already a member of the allocator, so that would make no sense. And there's no reason to make them part of the traits class.

Comment: yes, but `construct_range` can also be a (non) standard member. Also a free function. The problem is that I know what I want but I don't see any analogous design to follow to give a flexible and generic programming solution.

Comment: @alfC: Why wouldn't it follow the existing `uninitialized_` pattern, only you get to pass an allocator as well?

Comment: You mean as an extra first argument? yes, I am thinking in doing that. The `uninitialized_` portion of the name becomes redundant (given that there is an allocator argument). I the end I settled for  `template<class Alloc, class ForwardIt>
void value_construct(Alloc& a, ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last){... for(){ a.construct(std::addressof(current), Value());} ... }`. Also `copy(Alloc, It, It)`, `fill(Alloc, It, It)`, `move(Alloc, It, It)` and `default_construct(Alloc, It, It)`, `destry_n(Alloc, It, It)`. I am not 100% sure about removing the "uninitialized_" portion of the name.

Comment: @alfC: The "uninitialized" part is *really important*, because it lets the user know that the range is not over actual `value_type`s. Plus, actual `value_type`s ought to be *destroyed* before constructing new objects in their place.

Comment: ok I see. Regarding the second part of your comment, it confuses me, because functions like https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/uninitialized_value_construct do not destroy before placing the new value, I think that is the fundamental point of being an `uninitialized` routine, no?

Comment: @alfC: That was my point; that's why it's important to call out that the memory range is intended to contain uninitialized data.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I just wanted to make sure. Please look at my edit to the question with my final code.

Comment: The logic behind removing the `uninitialized_` part of the name was motivated by the thinking that, one wouldn't use an allocator if it were not uninitialialized, and if one were to do a "destructive assignment" (never saw that in the STL) one would call, first `destroy` and later `[uninitialized?]_construct_n(alloc,...)`. But, I guess it is better to be a bit redundant.

Comment: I found that the original proposal mentions alternative names for `uninitialized_value_construct/uninitialized_default_construct` which were `value_construct/default_initialize`. "The names uninitialized_value_construct and uninitialized_default_construct were the originally proposed names[...]. The words "construct" and "initialize" already imply operating on uninitialized memory so the repetition seems redundant. [...], however, the names have been left as per [Kona's] vote." http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0040r2.html

Comment: I found that Thrust has `thrust::detail::default_construct_range(alloc, first, n)` and that Boost has `boost::alloc_construct_n`. However, at the end, I rolled my own `alloc_*` functions https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/blob/master/include/multi/detail/adl.hpp?ref_type=heads#L448 so my containers work with scoped allocators  https://gitlab.com/correaa/boost-multi/-/blob/master/test/scoped_allocator.cpp?ref_type=heads#L130 . Thanks again for your help.